# Why do Beckett Mariner and Captain Freeman have different last names?

Tags: star-trek-lower-decks

Beckett Mariner is Captain Freeman's daughter. Why do they have different last names?

Comment: Possibly she changed it so she wouldn't immediately be recognized as Captain (or Admiral) Freeman's daughter?

Comment: Note sure there is a canon answer; Mike (the head writer) named her after his sister -- Beckett Mariner McMahan.  As far as I know, it's never been explained in the show, but then again, Star Trek is post-scarcity, post a lot of things, and names being based on your parents names is likely an outdated concept, still used by some, but by no means required.  I wouldn't be surprised if it is explained in the future, but hasn't been, up until now.

Comment: For what's it worth, my kids don't have my last name, they have my wife's last name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No canon reason has been given yet.**

---

[Various theories](https://www.reddit.com/r/LowerDecks/comments/p4zyzp/why_is_she_not_called_beckett_freeman/) abound, but the most likely is that Mariner is her middle name, one that she's adopted as her surname in order to avoid people realising that she's related to the various Starfleet officers under whom she's served; her mother [Captain Carol Freeman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Carol_Freeman) of the Cerritos and [Admiral Alonzo Freeman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alonzo_Freeman).

Adding weight to this theory is that the show's writer, Mike McMahan revealed in an interview that this character's name is based on his sister's name, and that Mariner is *her* middle name.

> I don't know if you guys can say this —  I'm actually not sure if
> we're allowed to say this — but **my sister's name is Beckett Mariner
> McMahan**, and so I was able to use her name as the lead character on
> the show, which I've always wanted to do. I don't think that's ever
> been publicly out there. My mom loves to watch the show when the
> captain goes, "Beckett!" because she thinks it's so awesome.
>
> <sub><sup>[Below Deck With Lower Decks: Mike McMahan Breaks Down Season One](https://intl.startrek.com/news/below-deck-with-lower-decks-mike-mcmahan-breaks-down-season-one)</sup></sub>

Comment: Whoops, I just realized I forgot to accept your answer. Well done!

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - Cheers, big ears